# What should be the org.gradle.java.home be?

Tags: java, android, gradle

I am setting up gradle and java for android development. Whenever I run the gradlew assembleDeug it shows the following error:-

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong: Value 'C:Program FilesJavajdk-19' given for org.gradle.java.home Gradle property is invalid (Java home supplied is invalid)

Try: Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
```

My "gradle.properties" is as follows :-

```
// set path of java, it will tell where java is.

 // the path may differ for you, find where java is & copy

 // that path here

 org.gradle.java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19 //I think this is the problem
```

What should I do? What should I keep as the value of org.gradle.java.home?

I setup a gradle folder following a yt tutorial and the video said that in the gradle.property file I should enter the path of the jdk. So I did and ran the gradlew assembleDebug command but had the above mentioned error. My java_home variable is set to the same location. What should I do?

Answer (score 2):

From the Gradle docs

> org.gradle.java.home=(path to JDK home)
>
> Specifies the Java home for the Gradle build process. The value can be set to either a jdk or jre location, however, depending on what your build does, using a JDK is safer. This does not affect the version of Java used to launch the Gradle client VM (see Environment variables). A reasonable default is derived from your environment (JAVA_HOME or the path to java) if the setting is unspecified.

Thus, a better way to solve your issue is, delete the below property from `gradle.properties`

```
org.gradle.java.home = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-19
```

And setup the Java path as outlined at https://www.java.com/en/download/help/path.html

Comment: I followed your instructions and also set up Java home following oracle documentation. Still the same error is shown? Sorry for being silly I am a newbie so all help is appreciated

Comment: Can you run the `java -version` command in CMD and share the output?

Comment: Output:-

java 19.0.1 2022-10-18
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 19.0.1+10-21)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 19.0.1+10-21, mixed mode, sharing)